# How to locate rigid supports to ensure force direction when pulling inelastic rope?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Please help to understand if placing "supports" (brown rods placed as example) can ensure direction of the force (black arrow) slightly up-left, not down applied to a blue ball when rope is pulled. Floor is rigid, green inelastic rope is connected on the right to the floor and pulled on the left to produce a force. No gravity, no friction, 2D setup, direction up/down meaning directions on the picture. Supports can be any shape, rigid only, fixed to the rope at any points, but not to the floor and can be only to the right of dotted line. TIA

If the answer is "no way", then could it be done if support can be connected to the floor? If rope is fixed to the floor not to the right of the ball but to the left?

[image]

Comment: Wait, are all supports supposed to be to the right of the dotted line and the ball completely to the left of the dotted line? If so, probably no force component by a support onto the ball is going to be upward (for a vertical dotted line at least, for a tilted one like in the picture it may differ).

Comment: @kricheli, yes, in initial form supports on the right. I "see" if one views ball+support as one object that rope just pulls, then only down. I'm not sure about same if end of support is fixed to a point on the rope; that end could not slide down, wouldn't it push other end up a little?